# IgniteException: NullPointerException

Tags: spring, ignite

Im using Ignite Version 2.2 and I try to build a Cache using the following CacheConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
public class IgniteConfig {

    @Bean(name = Identifiers.STANDARD_IGNITE_ITEM)
    @Qualifier(Identifiers.STANDARD_IGNITE_ITEM)
    public CacheConfiguration<String, StandardItem> standardItemsCacheConfiguration() {
        return this.getItemsStandardCacheConfiguration();
    }

    private CacheConfiguration<String, StandardItem> getItemsStandardCacheConfiguration() {
        CacheConfiguration<String, StandardItem> config = new CacheConfiguration<>(Identifiers.STANDARD_IGNITE_ITEM_CACHE);

        config.setName(Identifiers.STANDARD_IGNITE_ITEM_CACHE);
        config.setIndexedTypes(String.class, StandardItem.class);
        config.setAtomicityMode(CacheAtomicityMode.TRANSACTIONAL);
        config.setCacheStoreFactory(FactoryBuilder.factoryOf(StandardItemCacheStore.class.getName()));
        config.setReadThrough(true);
        config.setWriteThrough(true);
        config.setCopyOnRead(false);
        config.setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED);
        config.setOnheapCacheEnabled(true);

        return config;
    }
}
```

This is my CacheStoreAdapter:

```
public class StandardItemCacheStore extends CacheStoreAdapter<String, StandardItem> {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StandardItemCacheStore.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void loadCache(IgniteBiInClosure<String, StandardItem> clo, Object... args) {
        super.loadCache(clo, args);

        logger.info("Load standard items into ingite cache");

        final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

        Flux<StandardItem> items = new StandardItemDAO().getAllItems();

        items.subscribe(item -> {
            if (item != null) {
                counter.incrementAndGet();

                logging.info("Load item into cache: " + item.toString());

                clo.apply(item.getItemId(), item);
            }
        });

        items.doOnComplete(() -> {
           logger.info("Loaded " + counter + " standard items into ignite cache");
        });
    }

    @Override
    public StandardItem load(String key) throws CacheLoaderException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Cache.Entry<? extends String, ? extends StandardItem> entry) throws CacheWriterException {

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Object key) throws CacheWriterException {

    }
}
```

Unfortunately im never able to build my cache since there are NullPointers which I dont understand where they are coming from. I load the cache like the following:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyService.class.getName());

    private final IgniteCache<String, StandardItem> standardItemIgniteCache;

    public MyService(@Autowired @Qualifier(Identifiers.STANDARD_IGNITE_ITEM) CacheConfiguration<String, StandardItem> standardItemCacheConfiguration) {
        logger.info("Call service provider constructor");

        Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(new IgniteConfiguration());

        logger.info("Create standard items cache");

        this.standardItemIgniteCache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(standardItemCacheConfiguration);
        this.standardItemIgniteCache.loadCache(null);
    }
}

    // ....
}
```

When I start my service the loading of the cache starts (I see the logoutputs from the items in the loadCache function) but all of a sudden an Exception is thrown:

```
2017-11-28 21:23:36.462  INFO 6 --- [           main] i.s.p.p.d.cache.StandardItemCacheStore   : Loaded 35219 standard items into ignite cache
2017-11-28 21:23:36.510 ERROR 6 --- [           main] o.a.i.i.processors.task.GridTaskWorker   : Failed to obtain remote job result policy for result from ComputeTask.result(..) method (will fail the whole task): GridJobResultImpl [job=C2 [c=LoadCacheJobV2 [keepBinary=false]], sib=GridJobSiblingImpl [sesId=26703840061-6c03522c-008e-41f5-b144-a5a08d8c60d2, jobId=36703840061-6c03522c-008e-41f5-b144-a5a08d8c60d2, nodeId=048a70e3-8197-48e0-865f-213828842787, isJobDone=false], jobCtx=GridJobContextImpl [jobId=36703840061-6c03522c-008e-41f5-b144-a5a08d8c60d2, timeoutObj=null, attrs={}], node=TcpDiscoveryNode [id=048a70e3-8197-48e0-865f-213828842787, addrs=[127.0.0.1, 172.19.0.9], sockAddrs=[/127.0.0.1:47500, 7b9717decf77/172.19.0.9:47500], discPort=47500, order=4, intOrder=4, lastExchangeTime=1511904205042, loc=false, ver=2.2.0#20170915-sha1:5747ce6b, isClient=false], ex=class o.a.i.IgniteException: null, hasRes=true, isCancelled=false, isOccupied=true]

org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Remote job threw user exception (override or implement ComputeTask.result(..) method if you would like to have automatic failover for this exception).
        at org.apache.ignite.compute.ComputeTaskAdapter.result(ComputeTaskAdapter.java:101) ~[ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker$5.apply(GridTaskWorker.java:1027) [ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker$5.apply(GridTaskWorker.java:1020) [ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6640) [ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.result(GridTaskWorker.java:1020) [ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.onResponse(GridTaskWorker.java:838) [ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.processJobExecuteResponse(GridTaskProcessor.java:1066) [ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor$JobMessageListener.onMessage(GridTaskProcessor.java:1301) [ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1556) [ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1184) [ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:126) [ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1097) [ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: null
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2.execute(GridClosureProcessor.java:1850) ~[ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker$2.call(GridJobWorker.java:566) ~[ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.wrapThreadLoader(IgniteUtils.java:6608) [ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.execute0(GridJobWorker.java:560) ~[ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobWorker.body(GridJobWorker.java:489) ~[ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:110) ~[ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor.processJobExecuteRequest(GridJobProcessor.java:1115) ~[ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.job.GridJobProcessor$JobExecutionListener.onMessage(GridJobProcessor.java:1908) ~[ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1556) [ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1184) [ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:126) [ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1097) [ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_111]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_111]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJob.localExecute(GridCacheAdapter.java:5456) ~[ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$LoadCacheJobV2.localExecute(GridCacheAdapter.java:5505) ~[ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter$TopologyVersionAwareJob.execute(GridCacheAdapter.java:6120) ~[ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.compute.ComputeJobAdapter.call(ComputeJobAdapter.java:132) ~[ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.closure.GridClosureProcessor$C2.execute(GridClosureProcessor.java:1847) ~[ignite-core-2.2.0.jar!/:2.2.0]
        ... 14 common frames omitted
2017-11-24 16:13:57.319  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.a.i.i.p.r.p.tcp.GridTcpRestProtocol    : Command protocol successfully stopped: TCP binary
2017-11-24 16:13:57.467  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.a.i.i.p.cache.GridCacheProcessor       : Stopped cache [cacheName=ignite-sys-cache]
2017-11-24 16:13:57.468  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.a.i.i.p.cache.GridCacheProcessor       : Stopped cache [cacheName=standard_item_cache]
2017-11-24 16:13:57.469  INFO 6 --- [           main] o.a.i.i.p.cache.GridCacheProcessor       : Stopped cache [cacheName=backend_cache]
[16:13:57] Ignite node stopped OK [uptime=00:00:04:404]
2017-11-24 16:13:57.513  INFO 6 --- [           main] org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal  :
>>> +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> Ignite ver. 2.2.0#20170915-sha1:5747ce6b36f10b30d2142b9d90dad8e3049e8f74 stopped OK
>>> +---------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>>> Grid uptime: 00:00:04:404
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a combination of problems, that leads to such behaviour:

1. Your `loadCache` method is asynchronous. So, when you call `IgniteCache#loadCache()`, then execution is not blocked, and it returns almost immediately.
2. You start `Ignite` as a resource in a `try` block. So, when construction of `MyService` finishes, `Ignite` instance is closed. It means, that the whole node is destructed. This is why you see, that your caches are stopped.

So, if you move `Ignite` creation out of the `try` block, the problem should go away.

Comment: I implemented the changes which you suggested but im still getting the same error. I updated the code from my post. The cache is getting created and all the items are getting loaded successfully. after that the exception is thrown

Comment: @Mulgard Do you see this problem in the code, that goes first in your question, or in addition? In addition there is the exact same problem.

Comment: Yes I know that. I get the same Exception in both examples. In the Additional code block which I posted I just wanted to load the cache and destroy it afterwards. The log outputs say that the cache is getting loaded successfully and also that the cache is getting destroyed successfully and after that the same exception appears. And for the code at the beginning: I put out the try and its still the same.

Comment: @Mulgard Message about "cache loaded successfully" comes after loadCache operation finishes. But since your loadCache method is asynchronous, you are trying to load data even after this method returns, and cache is destroyed. This is where this exception comes from.

Comment: So, make sure, that no data is added to cache after loadCache method finishes its work.

Comment: I guess I do not understand what you mean. Lets take the first code example which I posted. I only load the cache. I do not destory it, I do not query it. I do nothing on it. Why should this exception be thrown after the cache got loaded?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160092/discussion-between-denis-and-mulgard).